# Bootstrap collapsed navbar adds 15px margin to the right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The bootstrap navbar add 15 margin on small devices.

I have debugged the page with firebug and i dont seem to find na solution of this. The margin iss added and the page is the streched 15px wider wich is not nice.

I had to manually set some margins in the navbar. Maybee this is cousing this problems, i don't know.

Had anbody any ideas?

I've uploaded the app to http://caliopa.ultimatefreehost.in/. REsize your browser to see the error.

[margin on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m246p.jpg)

Comment: why dont you show a fragment of your code where you think the problem occures.?

Comment: Please post a working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a Snippet. [mcve]

Comment: I have uploaded the application on the link in the post. You can see there.